# How to remove data from Tableview and mySQL database when using the .getSelectedItem

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

This will allow me to delete the selected item, and remove it from table view but I can't get it to be removed from MySQL database. I know I will need to use the query but I don't know how to get the selections id when you highlight it.

```
Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete Item");
HBox hBox3 = new HBox(10);
hBox3.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
hBox3.getChildren().add(deleteButton);
String query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ?";

deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> {
    ResultSet rs;
     Connection connection = null;

        Object selectedItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        try {
            while(table.getItems().remove(selectedItem)) {

                connection = Database.getDBConnection();
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);                  
            }               
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
             System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
         }
});
```

Comment: You're going to need to cast you selected item here: `Object selectedItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();`

Comment: Unless you've got multiple equal elements in the items list, using a `while` loop to remove one element that you know is in there is unnecessary and repeating the query to the db also is. Note that you've written the query to be used with `PreparedStatement`, so you should us one for the db update. (You need to use `executeUpdate()` for this btw, since it's not a query returning row(s).) Furthermore it would be a good idea to specify the type parameter for `TableView`. this way you avoid having to write down the cast to your object type manually... (You'll probably need it to access the id.)